# What is the NTRU parameter equivalent to security level 112, 128 and 192?

Tags: rsa, public-key, post-quantum-cryptography, ntru

I came across this [paper](https://ijarcce.com/upload/2017/february-17/IJARCCE%2062.pdf) which mentions this table, which states that NTRU 347 is equivalent to 112 bit security level

[image: PKC standards comparison]

However, in this paper, [Choosing parameters for NTRU](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/708.pdf) mentions that NTRU-401 is equivalent to 112 bit security
[image: NTRU Parameters]

Thus, I would like to ask what parameter of NTRU is equivalent to 112, 128, 192 bit security level

Comment: When reading such a paper first note which comparison they use https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/ otherwise this is a blind comparison. Actullay better comparison with security levels.

Comment: It seems that the first one uses the NIST's recommendation. If we assume that those tables uses the same comparison, then the parameters on the second table. So what is the question, then?

Comment: Yup, a better phrasing of my question would be what is the NTRU parameter corresponding to 112, 128 and 192 security levels

Comment: Doesn't the second table provides the parameters?

Comment: The question is that the NTRU parameters for 112 bit security is different for both tables. First table says NTRU-251 is 112 bit security, while second table says NTRU-401 is 112 bit security. So which is correct?

Comment: Because the years are different and if you assume they are correct which one will you choose? Also, they may present this according to their attacks. This is just a to you guide while reading the papers.

Comment: The second one is a bad review, Forget it!

Comment: https://ntru.org/f/variants-20181130.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not easy. There is an [estimator](https://github.com/jschanck/estimator) by  John Schanck. You can use this estimator to derive according to your requirements.

For example

| NTRU | Core-SVP (tuple Sieving) | Hybrid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 443 | ~93 | ~89 |
| 743 | ~176 | ~172 |

I've omitted the variant of the Core-SVP, for example, the core belongs to the Tuple lattice sieving. They are both used in the Core-SVP and in the Hybrid.